# JS calculations in loop shifts float coma to left every interations

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate vami from array of the data. In excel calculations results are correct but in js i am getting strange results. only first iteration is correct every other is sifting floats coma to left.

For example:

first result: 871.266   it is correct!

second: 92.1942 it should be 921.942

third: 8.87344 it should be 887.344

link in to the code and data: https://playcode.io/558739

```js
var prev_vami = 1000;
var previous_aum = 0;

var len = arr.length;
for (var id = 0; id < len; id++) { 

  var vami = prev_vami*(arr[id]['aum'] / (previous_aum + arr[id]['investment']));

  console.log(vami+"="+prev_vami+"*("+arr[id]['aum']+"/("+previous_aum+"+"+arr[id]['investment']+"))");

  prev_vami = vami;
  previous_aum = arr[id]['aum'];
}
```

```html
<script>
var arr = [{
    aum: "435633",
    investment: "500000"
  },
  {
    aum: "460971",
    investment: "0"
  },
  {
    aum: "443672",
    investment: "0"
  },
  {
    aum: "424702",
    investment: "0"
  },
  {
    aum: "456314",
    investment: "0"
  },
  {
    aum: "494695",
    investment: "0"
  },
  {
    aum: "490140",
    investment: "0"
  },
  {
    aum: "495633",
    investment: "0"
  }
];
</script>
```

Comment: What is the formula you want to calculate ? I looked on google and seems that you are missing a 1+ ... I could be wrong

Comment: i am using formula to calculate from AUM this formula works in excel correctly

Comment: I mean, what is the mathematical formula ? It is hard to know what you are trying to implement if you don't write the objective formula. What do you write in excel  to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your input data is of type `string` and it should be of type `number`. When doing mathematical operations involving strings in JavaScript, strange results can be expected. For example:

`'2000' * 2 = 4000`

`'2000' / 2 = 1000`

`'2000' + 2 = '20002'`

Below is a working snipped with corrected data types and some other simplifications.

***NOTE:*** If you receive your data as strings, you can use `parseFloat()` to convert it to numbers.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    aum: 435633,
    investment: 500000
  },
  {
    aum: 460971,
    investment: 0
  },
  {
    aum: 443672,
    investment: 0
  },
  {
    aum: 424702,
    investment: 0
  },
  {
    aum: 456314,
    investment: 0
  },
  {
    aum: 494695,
    investment: 0
  },
  {
    aum: 490140,
    investment: 0
  },
  {
    aum: 495633,
    investment: 0
  }
];

let dataElem = null;
let prev_vami = 1000;
let curr_vami = null;
let previous_aum = 0;

for (let idx = 0; idx < arr.length; idx++) {

  dataElem = arr[idx];

  curr_vami = prev_vami * (dataElem.aum / (previous_aum + dataElem.investment));

  console.log(curr_vami);

  prev_vami = curr_vami;
  previous_aum = dataElem.aum;
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solve problem i forgot about that JS uses the + for addition and concatenation.
so "1000"+ "50" = 100050  and 1000+50 = 1050